# Archive .json import on rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I'm having problems importing a .json file and saving the data inside it in the api database. My code is like this:

```
  def create
    content = JSON.parse(File.open(params[:products]).read)
    @product = Product.new(content)
    if @product.save
      render json: { message: 'Produto Salvo', data: @product }, status: 200
    else
      render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

The file(products.json)contains this data:

```
[{
  "title": "Brown eggs",
  "type": "dairy",
  "description": "Raw organic brown eggs in a basket",
  "filename": "0.jpg",
  "height": 600,
  "width": 400,
  "price": 28.1,
  "rating": 4
}, {
  "title": "Sweet fresh stawberry",
  "type": "fruit",
  "description": "Sweet fresh stawberry on the wooden table",
  "filename": "1.jpg",
  "height": 450,
  "width": 299,
  "price": 29.45,
  "rating": 4
}]
```

By the time I implement the method, all fields are saved as NIL:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 3, title: nil, product_type: nil, description: nil, filename: nil, height: nil, width: nil, price: nil, rating: nil, created_at: "2021-11-10 14:15:11.261454000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-11-10 14:15:11.261454000 +0000">]>
```

How do I save with the data correctly filled in?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reading in an array of multiple products?

I would suggest inserting a `binding.pry` between where you set `content` and where you set `@product`

Paste the value of `content` here and I think the solution will become clear.